# How to minimize $ab + bc + ca$ given $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$?

Tags: inequality, optimization, proof-writing, spherical-coordinates

The question is to prove that $ab + bc + ca$ lies in between $-1$ and $1$, given that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$.

I could prove the maxima by the following approach. I changed the coordinates to spherical coordinates:

$a = \cos A \\
b = \sin A \cos B \\
c = \sin A \sin B$

Using that $\cos X + \sin X$ always lies between $- \sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 2$ I proved that $a + b + c$ lies between $- \sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt 3$.

Using $(a + b + c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab + bc + ca)$ I could prove that $ab + bc + ca$ is maximum at $1$ but I can't prove the minima.

Comment: use the Lagrange Multiplier Method

Comment: Note:  I edited and reformatted your question pretty heavily.  Please check to make sure I didn't accidentally change your meaning (there were parts I really couldn't follow).

Comment: For future questions here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting functions.

Comment: This appeared in the Eötvös-Kürschák competition in 1910 ;-) http://www.batmath.it/matematica/raccolte_es/ek_competitions/ek_competitions.pdf

Comment: @Jack, to be honest, I have no idea what relation there is between your comment and the question!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: You are just finding the stationary points of a quadratic form over a sphere, hence it is enough to compute the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix associated with your quadratic form to solve the problem.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for editing. I don't know how to make it look more readable and good. But, why did you delete your answer. I was planning on studying it in detail in the morning but it's gone now.

Comment: @barto Hehe. I have a book which has problems from that Hungarian competition !

Comment: No problem, as to the editing.  As to the answer...it was voted down by someone who left no comment, so I am not sure if it was flawed in some way.  I deleted it because I didn't have time to go over it carefully.  Besides, it appears that there are several posted solutions.

Comment: @lulu You don't have to delete your answer just because someone down voted it. It had some cool theory I didn't know about like Lagrange multipliers and stuff.

Comment: As I say, perhaps it had a blunder.  Wouldn't be my first.  I'll review it and undelete it if it looks good.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Wow. I didn't understand any of that. I interpreted this as an inequality question, which could be approached from geometry. But, I didn't understand the jargon in your answer like 'stationary points' and 'quadratic points', and can't see how Eigen values and matrices can be introduced into the picture. Can you recommend some books where I can learn the connection in between all these things ?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca=\frac{1}{2}((a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+(c+a)^2)\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

From what you've done, $ab+bc+ca = \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2 - (a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2} \geq \dfrac{0 - 1}{2} = \dfrac{-1}{2}$, and this is the minimum value you sought. The minimum occurs when $a+b+c = 0, a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1$. To solve for $a,b,c$ you only need to find one solution of the system of $2$ equations above, then you are done. Since there are $3$ variables and only $2$ equations, you can take $c = \dfrac{1}{2}, \Rightarrow a, b$ are the solutions of the equation: $4x^2+2x-1 = 0$, thus $a = x = \dfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{4}, \Rightarrow b = -\dfrac{1}{2} - a = \dfrac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{4}$ by Viete's theorem on quadratic equation.

Comment: Cool. I don't know Viete's theorem though.

Answer (score 2):

The powerful Rayleigh quotient method can solve this problem, and many similar ones.

Indeed, this issue is equivalent to the maxi/minimization of the (Rayleigh) quotient $q(x)=\dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{a^2+b^2+c^2}=\dfrac{X^TAX}{X^TX}$ with $A=\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.
The general result is that such a  quotient takes its values in the closed interval $[\lambda_{min},\lambda_{max}]$ where $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{max}$ are resp. the minimal and maximal eigenvalues of $A$ and values $(a,b,c)$ providing the min (resp. max) are given by the associated (normed) eigenvectors.

Easy computations show that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1/2$ (multiplicity 2) and $1$, with associated normed eigenvectors:

- for $\lambda=-1/2$: $(a,b,c)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1,0,1)$ and $(a,b,c)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1,1,0)$,
- for $\lambda=1$: $(a,b,c)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)$.

Thus the interval of values taken by $ab+bc+ca$ is in between $\lambda_{min}=-0.5$ and $\lambda_{max}=1$, these extreme values being reached for vectors $(a,b,c)$ as given above.

For more on the Rayleigh quotient method, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient ; for statistical applications, have a look at the slides "Rayleigh quotient" in http://www.svcl.ucsd.edu/courses/ece271B-F09/

Besides this algebraic approach, there is a geometric interpretation: let $S_k$ be the surface with equation $xy+yz+zx=k$. The maximum and minimum values for $k$ correspond to the limit cases for which $S_k \cap B \neq \varnothing$ where $B$ denotes the unit sphere.

Comment: Can you tell me how to geometrically interpret Eigen values and apply them here ? I couldn't understand the first two lines.

Comment: @user230452 The best is to have a look at, and an understanding of, the Wikipedia reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient I gave.

Comment: I feel as if Wikipedia's exposition is already expecting me to know it before reading it. Is there a book that you can recommend ? I want to understand your approach because at my current level of knowledge, I find it startling to introduce Eigen values here.

Comment: I advise you the following book "Elementary Linear Algebra" by Howard Anton and Chris Rorres Applications version 9th edition J.Wiley paragraph 9.5 for quadratic forms