# Non-calculus approaches to minimizing $\frac{ab}{c} + \frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b}$ where $a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

I came across this (now closed) [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744478/suppose-a2b2c2-1-find-the-minimum-possible-value-of-fracabc-fra) which asks:

> Suppose that $a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 = 1$ for positive real numbers $a, b, c$. What is the minimum possible value of $\frac{ab}{c} + \frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b}$?

While I understand this sort question is straightforwardly (if tediously) solved using multivariable calculus and Lagrange Multipliers, I am curious if there are any more elegant solutions that involve inequalities or single variable techniques.

I'm fairy new to this sort of question, but I made a few attempts. Thanks to a [somewhat similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633536/how-to-minimize-ab-bc-ca-given-a2-b2-c2-1), I tried changing to spherical coordinates, but wasn't able to come up with any useful inequalities for the resulting trig expression.

I also noticed that the Cauchy-Swartz inequality implies:
$$
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{ab}{c} + \frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b} \right)^2 & \leq (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) \left(\left(\frac{b}{c}\right) ^2 + \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{b}{c}\right) ^2 + \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2
\end{align*}
$$
I'm not sure if this is relevant.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $x = \frac{ab}{c}$, $y = \frac{bc}{a}$, $z = \frac{ca}{b}$.

Note that $(x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2 \geq 0$, and hence
$$(x+y+z)^2 \geq 3(xy+yz+xz)$$
so that
$$\left(\frac{ab}{c} + \frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b}\right)^2 \geq 3(b^2 + c^2 + a^2) = 3$$
and thus
$$\frac{ab}{c} + \frac{bc}{a} + \frac{ca}{b} \geq\sqrt{3}.$$
Equality is obtained in the case $a=b=c=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer here . +1 !

Comment: @User See please better. My solution it's the same. I just got it without substitutions.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I see. Your solution starts with "For $a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ we obtain a value $\sqrt3$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value. ".  We are not interested in the rest of your solution.  Because before, you found the minimum by different methods or you used a software and you wrote proof based on this result.  This is useless in competition.  Finding is different, assuming is different.

Comment: @User For very many symmetric homogeneous polynomial inequalities the equality occurs for equality case of all variables. It gets a value $\sqrt3$ without any methods. It's just substitution. After this we need to prove that we got a minimal value, which I made. I really don't understand you. Maybe read better my solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg How do you define "for very many ?"  You're making a really non-mathematical comment, assuming I don't know anything about inequality.  My reputation is low, do you think I'm stupid? Consider to minimize $$(x^2-1)^2+(y^2-1)^2$$ subject to $x+y=1$ . Minimum doesn't occur when $x=y=1/2$ .

Comment: @User I don't need do define, what is it very many. Anyone, which proves inequalities, knows this.  For three variables there are case $(1,1,0)$ and more, but the case $(1,1,1)$ is most frequent. In any case, from this we open to prove inequalities. Firstly, we try to understand, where  the equality occurs.  It's not always helps, but it's always the first step. The case of the equality occurring helps to find a proof.

Comment: Great answer! Why do you need to state that $(x - y)^2 + (y - z)^2 + (z - x)^2 \geq 0$? How does the previous line follow from the next?

Answer (score 2):

Recall the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) $(R)$. We may and do assume in our case that $0< a\le b\le c$. Let $x_1\le x_2\le x_3$ be the three numbers
$abc/c^2$, $abc/b^2$, $abc/a^2$ from the problem, we want to minimize their sum. Note that $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1=a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. Then
$$
(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2 =x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+2\overset{(R)}\ge x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1+2
=1+2=\bbox[yellow]{\ 3\ }\ .
$$
So the asked minimal value of $x_1+x_2+x_3$ is $\ge \sqrt 3$, and for $a=b=c$ we reach this value, the minimal value.

Answer (score 0):

For $a=b=c=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ we obtain a value $\sqrt3$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2\geq abc\sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}$$ or after squaring
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^4-a^4b^2c^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}c^4(a^2-b^2)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Can downvoter explain me, why did you do it?